# Mirror Display Mode (Win10, AMD) - Visual LAG in DirectX/OpenGL apps

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, performance, display-driver

I have struggled with it enough not to find any decent solutions on the internet for this, very painful, issue.

Mirroring my display via Windows (10) Settings (<kbd>Win+P</kbd> -> Duplicate) causes the **video output on my main monitor to stutter** when a 3D app is running fullscreen (or even in a borderless windowed fullscreen), with some interesting conditions.

1. I have a monitor (main) and a TV on a wall (secondary display).
2. When in the Windows Settings the mode is set to "PC Screen only", everything works as expected - the FPS in the games is pretty good, nothing lags, VSync behaves as expected, etc.
3. When I switch to the Duplicate mode (or Extend, same issue), there goes the visual stutter on my monitor. I see the FPS to drop in games, **as well as** in the Windows itself while a game is minimized - I just drag some windows around and I clearly see that it moves with **like 15-20 FPS** or so - pretty ugly.
4. Interesting note: when it goes into the stutter mode, the **internal FPS is not decreased**! The Fraps software still shows the same number as it was before the Duplicate mode, that is, more than 100 FPS. But I see the lag with my own eyes, which means it should be, may be, very hardware.
5. Another note: when simply I open a fullscreen borderless video game, it stutters, but if I open it and **quickly switch** to some other app before it loads, than when it actually loads on the background (since the active focused window is in front), **then there is not stutter**! I can then switch back to the game and finally able to play it with full visual FPS, on both my displays, and with no lags whatsoever!
6. Exclusive fullscreen modes doesn't work that way as it said in the p.5, it stutters anyway.
7. MPC (video player) doesn't trigger the stutter to appear, although it uses borderless fullscreen mode.
8. Some games **do** trigger the stutter even when they are run in just a window.

---

- OS: The last, fully updated, Windows 10 x64.
- RAM: 16 GB
- CPU: Intel Core i5-4670 @ 3.4Ghz
- Video card: AMD Radeon R9 290
- Current video driver versions:

[image]
[image]

---

I tried using an older AMD driver, but with no success.

I also tried to using the **newest** AMD driver, but it's even more pain in the ass - when I start certain video games, the computer just FREEZES as it would if there was some real-time 1-threaded process in an infinite for loop. I had to go back to the older one for it to stop.

I tried to, according to some advice, turn off windows transparency, with no result.

How can I fix this? :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my main monitor with another one and the issue diappeared.

Possible reasons:

1. The previous monitor decided that it won't support Full HD FPS anymore while being mirrored to the TV on the wall.
2. AMD Driver software is broken and stopped supporting mirroring with my previous monitor.
3. Videocard didn't support HDMI+DVI mirroring enough to let me be happy. New monitor works via a different port, so current DisplayPort+DVI works pretty okay.